# Event ID 91 — AD CS Active Directory Domain Services Connection

Tags: active-directory, certificate

I have installed AD CA and I am getting this error(Event ID 91) :

```
A connection to Active Directory Directory Services could not be established. Active Directory Certificate Services will try to connect again when it needs Active Directory access.
```

it seems that CA cant connect to AD, I read [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) about that,
**PS:**

1. The ping to domain name and dc machine are normal
2. The permissions on essential AD DS containers and objects are fine
3. The result of nltest /sc_verify: [domainname] is :

   I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN

**I am using VMware for testing this scenario.**

but I still have this problem,
How can I solve that?
**Thanks in your Advise.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved by installing Windows Server 2008 SP2.